# Query to pull transactions where dispute date exceeds payment date by 120 days

Tags: sql, oracle

Super new with SQL and just was wanting a nudge in the right direction I have a payment table with column a) payment date and column b) dispute date. I want to pull all transactions where the dispute date exceeds the payment date by 120 days. I think it should have something to do with a CASE function but again super new to this!

```
SELECT merch_ref, payment_method, payment_date, dispute_date 
CASE WHEN dispute_date > (payment_date,120 dd) 
THEN 'NotLegit'
ELSE LEGIT
END 
FROM payment_table
```

This is my first question and was slightly anxious as I know there is a format that you guys like so, any hints and tips on how to improve my structure of questioning would also be super helpful.
On ORACLE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to pull all transactions where the dispute date exceeds the payment date by 120 days. I think it should have something to do with a CASE function but again super new to this!

What you are describing sounds more like filtering, which is `WHERE`, not `CASE`:

```
SELECT merch_ref, payment_method, payment_date, dispute_date 
FROM payment_table
WHERE disputer_date > payment_date + interval '120' day;
```

You would use a `CASE` expression to return a new column on each row, but (without a `WHERE`) all rows would be returned, not just the ones meeting your condition.

Comment: Ah yeah that makes total sense.. I think.. .just for my wee mushy brain to understand; 

So it would still be a load of transactions that would pulled in just using a CASE statement. Whilst running WHERE will actually only filter out the ones that match the conditions specified

Comment: ORA-01873: the leading precision of the interval is too small. Hi Gordon, this is what I got when I popped in your syntax. I am not familiar with this. Would this have something to do with the data format for either payment_date or dispute_date or maybe both?

Comment: @Looch . . . What is the data types of the  two columns?

Comment: I ran info+ on the table and both payment_date & dispute_date's data type are DATE

Comment: @Looch . . . The `case` expression does not filter values.  It would add a new column.  You might try `payment_date + 120`; it should be equivalent.

Comment: Thank you so much man! You have been super super helpful. Sorry for such a trivial question haha but definitely getting it now! Hope ya have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

Would this help?

```
SELECT merch_ref,
       payment_method,
       payment_date,
       dispute_date,
       --
       CASE
         WHEN dispute_date > payment_date + 120 THEN
           'NotLegit'
         ELSE
           'Legit'
       END status
FROM payment_table
```

Comment: Aw wow, thank you so much. Yeah that's exactly it. Super appreciative and really quick answer. You guys absolutely rock!